# Property marker menu items greyed out

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to develop my first Windows UWP app, following [this tutorial on creating a UI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/design/basics/xaml-basics-ui#part-1-add-a-textblock-using-xaml-designer). When I have added a TextBlock to MainPage.xaml, I can't choose System Resource from the property marker menu for the Style attribute, in the Properties window. Why is this? Am I missing a particular Visual Studio component?

If I try typing out the style specified in the tutorial `{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}`, IntelliSense does suggest these.

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound Although I haven't given it a name in the screenshot, the menu option still don't become enabled if I give it a name

Comment: @Ramhound The screenshot shows what's going on even if I do set the name. The name seems to be irrelevant for this issue.

Comment: Figured it out...

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing a particular Visual Studio component?

If that was the case you wouldn’t have even been able to choose the UWP project template nor place the TextBlock into the project.

> Why is this?

The instructions are simply wrong.

[image]

> In the Properties panel, enter style into the search box to find the
>   Style property. Click the property marker for the Style property to
>   open its menu. (The property marker is the small box symbol to the
>   right of each property value.) On the Property menu, select System
>   Resource > TitleTextBlockStyle. This applies a system-defined style to
>   your title text.

Instead you need to, right click on the object, hover over "Apply Resource" and then select `TitleTextBlockStyle` from the list.

The instructions indicate you are suppose to select System Resource, but that isn't actually correct, looked at the final product and they used `StaticResource` resulting in the following XAML

```
<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
                   Text="Collection"
                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                   Margin="24,0,0,24" />
```

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-photo-lab/blob/master/PhotoLab/MainPage.xaml)

Comment: This tutorial was created by the community.  This is the reason the tutorial use non-standard objects which are not actually free outside of a demo and the instructions are wrong.